# Apex Trigger to populate Lookup Relationship

Tags: trigger

I have a custom object - **Object 1** and the **Opportunity** object. I've created a lookup field from the **Opportunity** to **Object 1** and I want to be able to populate the id of a related record into the lookup field, in order to reference some of the values, back on the Opportunity.

The related records on the Object 1 are being created first, so I want my trigger to fire after the records are created, or modified.

I want the trigger to check if both objects share the same id and then populate the lookup.

The id on the Opportunity is stored in a custom field = field_1__c and the id on the custom object Object_1__c is stored in a custom field = field_2__c and they have to match, before populate the lookup.

This is what I have built so far, but I am not having much success... so a little bit of help, it's much appreciated

```
trigger UpdateLookup on Object_1__c (after insert, after update){
for (Object_1__c obj: trigger.new){
    Obj1Ids.add(obj.id);
}

Map <Opportunity> matchingIdsMap = new Map <Opportunity> ();

for (Opportunity obj: [Select Id, field_1__c from Opportunity, where id in:ObjIds]){
matchingIdsMap.put(Opportunity.id, Opportunity);
}

List <Opportunity>OpportunitiesToUpdate = new List <Opportunity> ();

for (Object_1__c obj: trigger.new){

if (matchingIdsMap.get(obj.id) ! = null)



{

   matchingIdsMap.get(obj.id).Object_1__C = ObjIds;

   OpportunitiesToUpdate.add (matchingIdsMap.get(ObjIds));

}

update OpportunitiesToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: "it only works if there is a value in the lookup field, which it's not the requirement" - how are you expecting it to work? The behavior you're describing sounds like it's working as designed.

Comment: @DavidReed - Hi David, Thanks for coming back to me. I have amended the post to make more sense. What I meant by "it's not the requirement", is that this is not what I want to achieve. :) I know it's working as designed.

Comment: What David was getting at is it's not clear from where you would pull the data in the case where the lookup is empty.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - The lookup will always be empty, as I've only created it as bridge between the 2 objects. One Opp will have multiple records on the custom object. The only way to know to what Opportunity are those related is through 2 custom fields - one on the Opportunity (having an unique id) and one the custom object (having the unique id the Opportunity has)

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I've also tried creating a PB on the custom object, but it fails. The process starts on the Custom Object (when a record is created or edited), checks if conditions are met: [customobject__c].oppid__c = [customobject__].opportunity__r.oppid__c, if the conditions are met then update records: [customobject__c].opportunities__r (field: custom field (opportunity) field reference [customfield__c].oppid__c. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - The error: Error 'The flow failed to access the value because it hasn't been set or assigned' - and found this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315965&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 , which answers my question, as the lookup field even from the custom object to the Opportunity will always be empty, as the integration will never write back to it, so I assume the trigger is the only option?

Comment: Please don't `@mention` people who are trying to get you to clarify your question, nor provide that clarification in the comments. Rather, **[edit]** your post to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The lookup will always be empty, as I've only created it as bridge between the 2 objects. One Opp will have multiple records on the custom object. The only way to know to what Opportunity are those related is through 2 custom fields - one on the Opportunity (having an unique id) and one the custom object (having the unique id the Opportunity has)

This fundamentally is not what lookup relationships do. Salesforce does not have a notion of a "bridge" between objects that gets populated automatically (absent perhaps the use of External Objects, which you don't seem to be using here).

You need to populate the Id of a related record into the lookup field in order to be able to reference values on that related object. It makes no difference which automation tool you use to attempt the field access.

You will need to create automation in your org to populate the lookup field based on querying the shared "unique id" you mention. The tools capable of doing so are Apex and Process + Flow (not Process Builder alone). I would recommend an Apex trigger.

Only once this lookup field is populated will you be able to use formula fields or any other tool to traverse the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, David. I started looking into a trigger after your reply, but I haven't had much luck, so I have amended the post for help :)

Comment: @SSimion Your trigger appears to be on the wrong object (should be Opportunity), and it will not compile due to a large number of syntax errors. Please also note that two distinct Salesforce objects will _never_ have the same `Id` value. I'd recommend completing some of the core Apex trailhead modules to nail down the syntax of the language and revisiting the trigger.